# Eclipse connection to update maven indexes hangs

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven

I just moved to Mac and trying to migrate my projects, some dependencies are not recognised, eclipse hangs trying to connect to the central maven repo, when I go on safari I can navigate to the repo "https://repo.maven.apache.org./maven2/", however from eclipse it just hangs

any eclipse fans who can tell me a way around this?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy/firewall? Some company proxies check the User Agent of the request, and block requests that do not have "browser-like" User Agents.

Comment: hi, no this is the same even from home, I cloned my project to migrate to Mac. It's only the hibernate JPA dependency that cannot be resolved, but under maven dependencies it is there. I would add a screenshot here, but I don't see the option

Comment: Please try to build your project with `clean install` and report the errors.

Comment: [WARNING] error reading /Users/eihabagladious/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[WARNING] error reading /Users/eihabagladious/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Comment: Then delete the complete content of `/Users/eihabagladious/.m2/repository/` and try again.

Comment: I did, now eclipse is waiting at this line:    [INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar (44 KB at 12.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.16.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar

Comment: that solved the type not found :) thank you!! any explanation why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially written files in your local repository confused Maven. It could not read but did not try to redownload them (because they were already there).